# Functional eqation problem

Tags: functional-equations

Is there a function $f: \mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ that satisfies $$f(f(n-1))=f(n+1)-f(n)$$ for $n \geq 2$? So far I just know that $f(n)>f(n-1)$ for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183558/prove-that-there-is-no-function-f-mathbbz-ge-0-rightarrow-mathbbz-ge for case when $0 \in \mathbb{N}$